# Crear un botón para descargar información

Tags: json

Muy buenas, en mi codigo estoy subiendo un archivo json así:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function (e) {
                            //console.log('e readAsText = ', e);
                            //console.log('e readAsText target = ', e.target);

                            var json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);

                            //console.log(json)
                            var jsonprueba = json

}
```

Luego de eso necesito editar el json que subí, y crear un boton para descargar el json nuevo con la edición, no se me ocurre como crear la descarga asi sea de algo que no está hecho.

Todo es Javascript

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Independientemente del trato o modificación que des a tu objeto, cuando hayas terminado de trabajar con él y tengas un JSON válido, puedes usar esta función para descargar el archivo:

```
function downloadObjectAsJson(exportObj, exportName) {
  var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(exportObj));
  var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", exportName + ".json");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
  downloadAnchorNode.click();
  downloadAnchorNode.remove();
}
```

El parámetro `exportObj` hace referencia a un objeto JSON válido, y `exportName` sería el nombre que quieres para el archivo que se descargará (sin extensión).

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
var myJSONObject = {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
  "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
   "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
     "SortAs": "SGML",
     "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
     "Acronym": "SGML",
     "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
     "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
      "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
     "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }

};

downloadObjectAsJson(myJSONObject,'myjs');
/*
   Posteada originalmente aquí:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800715/5587982
 */
function downloadObjectAsJson(exportObj, exportName) {
  var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(exportObj));
  var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", exportName + ".json");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode); // required for firefox
  downloadAnchorNode.click();
  downloadAnchorNode.remove();
}
```

---

#### Fuente:

- **[Respuesta de @volzo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800715/5587982)**  a la pregunta *[Download JSON object as a file from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19721439/5587982)* publicada en Stackoverflow en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

{
"model": "gpt-4",
"messages": [
{
"role": "user",
"content": "Analyze the pros and cons of remote work vs. office work"
}
],
"temperature": 0.8,
"max_tokens": 64,
"top_p": 1
}

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/402227)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).